# Send email from cell value google sheet, with other columns in email

Tags: excel, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologises as I know this has been asked a few times, which I have learnt from other questions, however I'm still stuck and not sure how to continue.

I'm trying to make a google script to send an email notification to more then one person, based on a cell change, also sending in the email multiple cell values in the same row?

e.g. If Column 'C' changes, can I send an email with data from Column 'A' and 'B' in the same Row of the change in column 'C'?

This is the script I've been trying to play around with but not sure how to add multiple e-mails, and values from two more cells.

```
function sendNotifications() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
var recipients = email@domain.com";
var message = '';
var cellA = ''
if(cell.indexOf('B')!=-1){ 
message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
}
var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
var body = + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

Comment: You can send to multiple recipients by separating the addresses by a `,`. Acquiring the data from another cell could be done through [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))

Answer (score 1):

The code below checks if the edited cell was in column C and, if the condition is met, gets the values for columns A and B from the edited row. In Google Apps Script, onEdit() is the built-in function that fires automatically when you make changes in your spreadsheet. The 'e' parameter represents the event object that you can inspect to get more details about the context in which the event occurred

```
function onEdit(e){

  var editRange = e.range; // e is the event object generated by the Edit event
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();   // get row and column for the edited cell
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                            .getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // put your sheet name between the brackets

  if (editCol == 3) {   // checking if the edited cell was in column C

      var range = sheet.getRange(editRow, 1, 1, editCol - 1); // Take 1st cell in the edited row and make it span 1 row and 2 columns
      var values = range.getValues(); // get values array for the range
      Logger.log(values);

  }

}
```

The resulting variable ('values') is an array, so you must loop through it to get string values. As for the emails, you could store multiple emails in a cell, separated by comma. Calling split() method on a string will get you an array of values (emails) that you can then pass to the sendEmail method as the first parameter.

```
  var cellValue = "email@example.com,anotheremail@example.com,yetanotheremail@example.com";
  var recipients = cellValue.split(",");  
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, "From google-apps-script", "hello from google apps script")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anton, that script seems to send me an e-mail on any cell that is edited regardless of if its Column C? Also how do I get the Columns next to column C (e.g. A and B) inside the body of the e-mail sent? like "Hello Column (a value), (b value) has been updated!"

Comment: Please take some time to read Google Apps Script documentation and understand the basics of JavaScript. Otherwise, it looks like you want someone to do all the coding for you, which is not what StackOverflow is for. The last parameter in sendEmail() method is the body of the email that you can form by concatenating a string from cell values. You can also tie these pieces of code together and send the email only if the edited value was in column 3 (C).